# Extract Information from XML Document Attributes into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, xml

I am fairly new to SQL, and very unfamiliar with XML. I want to extract the key data from the XML document below into PostgreSQL, but I am having difficulties. Basically, for every data series, I would like to parse all of the attributes, as well as the values for the different years. Can anyone help me out please? It seems that the XML document is particularly peculiar.

The expected output I would like is as follows:

```
Series          Period        Value            
FG384104005.Q    2017-12-31  4.856960795039409    
FG384104005.Q    2018-03-31  6.685299171442962     
.....
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<message:MessageGroup xmlns:message="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message" xmlns:common="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/common" xmlns:frb="http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message SDMXMessage.xsd http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/common frb_common.xsd">
  <message:Header xmlns:message="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message">
    <message:ID>OTHER</message:ID>
    <message:Test>false</message:Test>
    <message:Name>Z.1 Statistical Release</message:Name>
    <message:Prepared>2019-09-19T23:31:06</message:Prepared>
    <message:Sender id="FRB">
      <message:Name>Federal Reserve Board</message:Name>
      <message:Contact>
        <message:Name>Financial Accounts of the United States Z.1 Coordinator</message:Name>
        <message:Telephone>(202)-452-3000</message:Telephone>
      </message:Contact>
    </message:Sender>
  </message:Header>
  <frb:DataSet id="Z1" xmlns:kf="http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/Z1_Z1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/Z1_Z1 Z1_Z1.xsd">
    <kf:Series CURRENCY="NA" FREQ="162" SERIES_INSTRUMENT="41040" SERIES_NAME="FG384104005.Q" SERIES_PREFIX="FG" SERIES_SECTOR="38" SERIES_TYPE="5" UNIT="Percent" UNIT_MULT="1">
      <frb:Annotations>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Short Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Domestic nonfinancial sectors; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Long Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Domestic nonfinancial sectors; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
      </frb:Annotations>
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.825831484374212" TIME_PERIOD="2017-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="6.685299171442962" TIME_PERIOD="2018-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.922904576231467" TIME_PERIOD="2018-06-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.130042303121223" TIME_PERIOD="2018-09-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.377391222747768" TIME_PERIOD="2018-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="5.905098159371182" TIME_PERIOD="2019-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.142025368753797" TIME_PERIOD="2019-06-30" />
    </kf:Series>
    <kf:Series CURRENCY="NA" FREQ="162" SERIES_INSTRUMENT="41040" SERIES_NAME="FG154104005.Q" SERIES_PREFIX="FG" SERIES_SECTOR="15" SERIES_TYPE="5" UNIT="Percent" UNIT_MULT="1">
      <frb:Annotations>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Short Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Households and nonprofit organizations; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Long Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Households and nonprofit organizations; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
      </frb:Annotations>
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="5.084259576315951" TIME_PERIOD="2017-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.994283100284392" TIME_PERIOD="2018-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.357940781533728" TIME_PERIOD="2018-06-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.382807703277534" TIME_PERIOD="2018-09-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.915212086558261" TIME_PERIOD="2018-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.072911152729307" TIME_PERIOD="2019-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.265474038700484" TIME_PERIOD="2019-06-30" />
    </kf:Series>
    <kf:Series CURRENCY="NA" FREQ="162" SERIES_INSTRUMENT="31651" SERIES_NAME="FG153165105.Q" SERIES_PREFIX="FG" SERIES_SECTOR="15" SERIES_TYPE="5" UNIT="Percent" UNIT_MULT="1">
      <frb:Annotations>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Short Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Households and nonprofit organizations; home mortgages; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Long Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Households and nonprofit organizations; home mortgages; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
      </frb:Annotations>
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.190052017480996" TIME_PERIOD="2017-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.590072043418194" TIME_PERIOD="2018-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.343399749580076" TIME_PERIOD="2018-06-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.108870948819421" TIME_PERIOD="2018-09-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.368108520717171" TIME_PERIOD="2018-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.190939916139975" TIME_PERIOD="2019-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.183395534476023" TIME_PERIOD="2019-06-30" />
    </kf:Series>
    <kf:Series CURRENCY="NA" FREQ="162" SERIES_INSTRUMENT="31660" SERIES_NAME="FG153166000.Q" SERIES_PREFIX="FG" SERIES_SECTOR="15" SERIES_TYPE="0" UNIT="Percent" UNIT_MULT="1">
      <frb:Annotations>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Short Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Households and nonprofit organizations; consumer credit; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Long Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Households and nonprofit organizations; consumer credit; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
      </frb:Annotations>
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="6.158260115598504" TIME_PERIOD="2017-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.554759020656510" TIME_PERIOD="2018-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.231760626750670" TIME_PERIOD="2018-06-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="5.462344733253373" TIME_PERIOD="2018-09-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="5.432498874027520" TIME_PERIOD="2018-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.268915782478897" TIME_PERIOD="2019-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.640293079973249" TIME_PERIOD="2019-06-30" />
    </kf:Series>
    <kf:Series CURRENCY="NA" FREQ="162" SERIES_INSTRUMENT="41040" SERIES_NAME="FG144104005.Q" SERIES_PREFIX="FG" SERIES_SECTOR="14" SERIES_TYPE="5" UNIT="Percent" UNIT_MULT="1">
      <frb:Annotations>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Short Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Nonfinancial business; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Long Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Nonfinancial business; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
      </frb:Annotations>
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.856960795039409" TIME_PERIOD="2017-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.937026292209636" TIME_PERIOD="2018-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.368250237127337" TIME_PERIOD="2018-06-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.939649024335195" TIME_PERIOD="2018-09-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.527273794666953" TIME_PERIOD="2018-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="6.679776228429807" TIME_PERIOD="2019-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.364320285758023" TIME_PERIOD="2019-06-30" />
    </kf:Series>
    <kf:Series CURRENCY="NA" FREQ="162" SERIES_INSTRUMENT="41040" SERIES_NAME="FG104104005.Q" SERIES_PREFIX="FG" SERIES_SECTOR="10" SERIES_TYPE="5" UNIT="Percent" UNIT_MULT="1">
      <frb:Annotations>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Short Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Nonfinancial corporate business; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Long Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Nonfinancial corporate business; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
      </frb:Annotations>
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.503452371709450" TIME_PERIOD="2017-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.670254159879930" TIME_PERIOD="2018-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="1.309016868338993" TIME_PERIOD="2018-06-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.191176501703054" TIME_PERIOD="2018-09-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.041634403281393" TIME_PERIOD="2018-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="7.590014224313086" TIME_PERIOD="2019-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.279407898561263" TIME_PERIOD="2019-06-30" />
    </kf:Series>
    <kf:Series CURRENCY="NA" FREQ="162" SERIES_INSTRUMENT="41040" SERIES_NAME="FG314104005.Q" SERIES_PREFIX="FG" SERIES_SECTOR="31" SERIES_TYPE="5" UNIT="Percent" UNIT_MULT="1">
      <frb:Annotations>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Short Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Federal government; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Long Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Federal government; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
      </frb:Annotations>
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="1.785825656428645" TIME_PERIOD="2017-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="14.288117205171471" TIME_PERIOD="2018-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="5.663750800146286" TIME_PERIOD="2018-06-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="5.947833760197000" TIME_PERIOD="2018-09-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.659446647972927" TIME_PERIOD="2018-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="9.799654480658001" TIME_PERIOD="2019-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.084444919189768" TIME_PERIOD="2019-06-30" />
    </kf:Series>
    <kf:Series CURRENCY="NA" FREQ="162" SERIES_INSTRUMENT="41040" SERIES_NAME="FG214104005.Q" SERIES_PREFIX="FG" SERIES_SECTOR="21" SERIES_TYPE="5" UNIT="Percent" UNIT_MULT="1">
      <frb:Annotations>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Short Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>State and local governments, excluding employee retirement funds; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Long Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>State and local governments, excluding employee retirement funds; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
      </frb:Annotations>
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="3.928584786168869" TIME_PERIOD="2017-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="-3.198453580216953" TIME_PERIOD="2018-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="-0.364751393518411" TIME_PERIOD="2018-06-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="-1.493354542386708" TIME_PERIOD="2018-09-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="-1.575085049703778" TIME_PERIOD="2018-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="-1.163191483206581" TIME_PERIOD="2019-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="-2.510471166127347" TIME_PERIOD="2019-06-30" />
    </kf:Series>
    <kf:Series CURRENCY="NA" FREQ="162" SERIES_INSTRUMENT="41040" SERIES_NAME="FG794104005.Q" SERIES_PREFIX="FG" SERIES_SECTOR="79" SERIES_TYPE="5" UNIT="Percent" UNIT_MULT="1">
      <frb:Annotations>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Short Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Domestic financial sectors; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Long Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Domestic financial sectors; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
      </frb:Annotations>
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="0.159348908897592" TIME_PERIOD="2017-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="1.678531748037725" TIME_PERIOD="2018-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.226028889034942" TIME_PERIOD="2018-06-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="1.844495517503089" TIME_PERIOD="2018-09-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.848153667727601" TIME_PERIOD="2018-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.027952718415100" TIME_PERIOD="2019-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="2.490888053624153" TIME_PERIOD="2019-06-30" />
    </kf:Series>
    <kf:Series CURRENCY="NA" FREQ="162" SERIES_INSTRUMENT="41040" SERIES_NAME="FG264104005.Q" SERIES_PREFIX="FG" SERIES_SECTOR="26" SERIES_TYPE="5" UNIT="Percent" UNIT_MULT="1">
      <frb:Annotations>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Short Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Rest of the world; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
        <common:Annotation>
          <common:AnnotationType>Long Description</common:AnnotationType>
          <common:AnnotationText>Rest of the world; debt securities and loans; liability</common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
      </frb:Annotations>
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="16.232882216382549" TIME_PERIOD="2017-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="9.322037677591291" TIME_PERIOD="2018-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.467988888014356" TIME_PERIOD="2018-06-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="5.907598117735855" TIME_PERIOD="2018-09-30" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="-1.598513733891009" TIME_PERIOD="2018-12-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="-1.617225073562540" TIME_PERIOD="2019-03-31" />
      <frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="9.883975645208007" TIME_PERIOD="2019-06-30" />
    </kf:Series>
  </frb:DataSet>
</message:MessageGroup>
```

Comment: I would load the XML into a temporary table and run [`xpath`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) queries on it.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the expected output you want as formatted text. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Okay, just edited the comment. Laurenz, yes, I want to run xpath questions on it --- but I'm having a lot of trouble with actually getting information on the ATTRIBUTES of the XML document. Would appreciate help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite tricky because of the nested namespaces and tags.

To process something like that, `xmltable()` is the best choice (available since Postgres 10).

```sql
select series.series_name, obs.*
from jacob j
  cross join xmltable(XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message' AS message,
                                   'http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/common' AS frb,
                                   'http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/Z1_Z1' as kf),
      '/message:MessageGroup/frb:DataSet/kf:Series'
      passing j.document
      columns series_name text path '@SERIES_NAME', 
              content xml path '.') as series
  left join xmltable(XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message' AS message,
                                   'http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/common' AS frb,
                                   'http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/Z1_Z1' as kf),
       'kf:Series/frb:Obs'
       passing series.content
       columns obs_value numeric path '@OBS_VALUE',
               time_period date path '@TIME_PERIOD') as obs on true
```

The first xmltable() usage retrieves all `Series` tags from the document in order to be able to extract the series_name (so if the XML contains more than one `<kf:Series>` this would return multiple rows.

As the periods are contained as a nested list of tags, we need another `xmltable()` call to which we pass all the `<frb:Obs>` tags. To be able to do that, the first `xmltable` returns the inner content of the `<kf:Series>` tag as an XML value which is then used in the next `xmltable()` through `passing series.content`

I have used a `left join` for the second `xmltable` to make sure the series is returned even if there are no `<kf:Obs>` sub-tags in the content.

The result of the above given your input is:

```
series_name   | obs_value          | time_period
--------------+--------------------+------------
FG384104005.Q |  3.825831484374212 | 2017-12-31 
FG384104005.Q |  6.685299171442962 | 2018-03-31 
FG384104005.Q |  3.922904576231467 | 2018-06-30 
FG384104005.Q |  4.130042303121223 | 2018-09-30 
FG384104005.Q |  3.377391222747768 | 2018-12-31 
FG384104005.Q |  5.905098159371182 | 2019-03-31 
FG384104005.Q |  3.142025368753797 | 2019-06-30 
FG154104005.Q |  5.084259576315951 | 2017-12-31 
FG154104005.Q |  2.994283100284392 | 2018-03-31 
FG154104005.Q |  3.357940781533728 | 2018-06-30 
FG154104005.Q |  3.382807703277534 | 2018-09-30 
FG154104005.Q |  2.915212086558261 | 2018-12-31 
FG154104005.Q |  2.072911152729307 | 2019-03-31 
FG154104005.Q |  4.265474038700484 | 2019-06-30 
FG153165105.Q |  3.190052017480996 | 2017-12-31 
FG153165105.Q |  2.590072043418194 | 2018-03-31 
FG153165105.Q |  3.343399749580076 | 2018-06-30 
FG153165105.Q |  3.108870948819421 | 2018-09-30 
FG153165105.Q |  2.368108520717171 | 2018-12-31 
FG153165105.Q |  2.190939916139975 | 2019-03-31 
FG153165105.Q |  3.183395534476023 | 2019-06-30 
FG153166000.Q |  6.158260115598504 | 2017-12-31 
FG153166000.Q |  3.554759020656510 | 2018-03-31 
FG153166000.Q |  4.231760626750670 | 2018-06-30 
FG153166000.Q |  5.462344733253373 | 2018-09-30 
FG153166000.Q |  5.432498874027520 | 2018-12-31 
FG153166000.Q |  4.268915782478897 | 2019-03-31 
FG153166000.Q |  4.640293079973249 | 2019-06-30 
FG144104005.Q |  4.856960795039409 | 2017-12-31 
FG144104005.Q |  3.937026292209636 | 2018-03-31 
FG144104005.Q |  3.368250237127337 | 2018-06-30 
FG144104005.Q |  3.939649024335195 | 2018-09-30 
FG144104005.Q |  4.527273794666953 | 2018-12-31 
FG144104005.Q |  6.679776228429807 | 2019-03-31 
FG144104005.Q |  4.364320285758023 | 2019-06-30 
FG104104005.Q |  3.503452371709450 | 2017-12-31 
FG104104005.Q |  3.670254159879930 | 2018-03-31 
FG104104005.Q |  1.309016868338993 | 2018-06-30 
FG104104005.Q |  4.191176501703054 | 2018-09-30 
FG104104005.Q |  2.041634403281393 | 2018-12-31 
FG104104005.Q |  7.590014224313086 | 2019-03-31 
FG104104005.Q |  4.279407898561263 | 2019-06-30 
FG314104005.Q |  1.785825656428645 | 2017-12-31 
FG314104005.Q | 14.288117205171471 | 2018-03-31 
FG314104005.Q |  5.663750800146286 | 2018-06-30 
FG314104005.Q |  5.947833760197000 | 2018-09-30 
FG314104005.Q |  3.659446647972927 | 2018-12-31 
FG314104005.Q |  9.799654480658001 | 2019-03-31 
FG314104005.Q |  2.084444919189768 | 2019-06-30 
FG214104005.Q |  3.928584786168869 | 2017-12-31 
FG214104005.Q | -3.198453580216953 | 2018-03-31 
FG214104005.Q | -0.364751393518411 | 2018-06-30 
FG214104005.Q | -1.493354542386708 | 2018-09-30 
FG214104005.Q | -1.575085049703778 | 2018-12-31 
FG214104005.Q | -1.163191483206581 | 2019-03-31 
FG214104005.Q | -2.510471166127347 | 2019-06-30 
FG794104005.Q |  0.159348908897592 | 2017-12-31 
FG794104005.Q |  1.678531748037725 | 2018-03-31 
FG794104005.Q |  2.226028889034942 | 2018-06-30 
FG794104005.Q |  1.844495517503089 | 2018-09-30 
FG794104005.Q |  2.848153667727601 | 2018-12-31 
FG794104005.Q |  2.027952718415100 | 2019-03-31 
FG794104005.Q |  2.490888053624153 | 2019-06-30 
FG264104005.Q | 16.232882216382549 | 2017-12-31 
FG264104005.Q |  9.322037677591291 | 2018-03-31 
FG264104005.Q |  4.467988888014356 | 2018-06-30 
FG264104005.Q |  5.907598117735855 | 2018-09-30 
FG264104005.Q | -1.598513733891009 | 2018-12-31 
FG264104005.Q | -1.617225073562540 | 2019-03-31 
FG264104005.Q |  9.883975645208007 | 2019-06-30
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=14fe67be2eb8baae6fe2da3ca21a1e9b)